# How to ignore the "" in the XML using XSLT while converting it to JSON?

Tags: json, xml, xslt

I am new to XML. I am trying to convert XML to JSON using XSLT. However, the JSON file generated with the XML content is failing validation due to one of the line items which looks like this:

```
{"Name": ""
        Your name is " Pablo Picasso"}
```

I'm looking for a solution where I can ignore the inner quotes of the xml content. ("Your name is")

**How can I resolve this using XSLT?**

The error message on the JSON validator that I get is as follows:

```
Error: Parse error on line 1211:
...}, {     "Name": ""      You name is " 
---------------------^
Expecting 'EOF', '}', ':', ',', ']', got 'undefined'
```

Comment: Only seeing your output, it's difficult to understand what you might be doing wrong. Can you show your source XML and XSLT?

Comment: Inner quotes need to be escaped, not ignored. In addition to showing your input and your current XSLT, state also which XSLT processor you will be using - since the solution will depend on the version of XSLT it supports.

Comment: If you can move to XSLT 3 with JSON serialization and conversion functions like `xml-to-json` supported (easily possible on the Java and .NET framework platform with Saxon 9.8 HE and later or also with an XML IDE like Altova XML Spy R 2017 3 and later). Like any other format with strict syntax rules it is usually best to use/exploit APIs/functions that are dedicated to creating such a format, ensuring that the output meets the syntactic rules.

Comment: If you're using an XML-to-JSON converter that produces invalid JSON then you need a better converter. There are plenty around. We can't help you further without knowing more precisely how you are doing the conversion.